# Javascript: Cheking if an array has a special symbol

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im newbie and im still learning javascript. With the current exercises which are working with while loops, we were given an exercise to check if an array has special symbols. Each elememt in the array that is not a symbol is added to a variable that will form a word at the end. My question is how do i check if an element in an array is a symbol or a letter.

```js
function solve(input) {
  let i = 0
  let command = input[i]
  let secret = 0
  let word = 0
  while (command !== "End") {
    let current = input[i]
    console.log(current)

    i++
    command = input[i]
  }

}

solve(["H", "n", "e", "l", "l", "o", "o", "c", "t", "c", "h", "o", "e", "r", "e", "n", "e", "End"])
```

This code will show the elements of the array untill it hits the element "End".
If it is a letter and not a symbol, it is added to the variable - word which at the end will form a word or phrase.
But if it is symbol it is not added to the variable word.
How do i check if an element is a symbol or a letter? I didn't try anything because nothing was related to my problem or i just couldn't apply it properly.

Comment: you can use regex  with match method  ```console.log("e".match(/\w/g))```

[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) 

```\w ```  Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the unicode of each character and put a condition.

```js
   function solve(input) {
        let i = 0
        let command = input[i]
        let secret = 0
        let word = 0
     while (command !== "End") {
         let current = input[i]
         let uni = current.charCodeAt(0)
         if((uni>=65 && uni<=90) || (uni>=97&&uni<=122))
         {
         console.log(current)
         }
        
        i++
        command=input[i]
     }
        
    }
    solve(["H",
        "n",
        "e",
        "l",
        "l",
        "o",
        "o",
        "c",
        "t",
        "c",
        "h",
        "$",
        "#",
        "o",
        "e",
        "r",
        "e",
        "n",
        "e",
        "End",
        ])
```

Comment: I'd like to thank you a lot! This simple knowledge helped me with the exercise a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact: Due to javascript's automatic typecasting you can compare characters with greater-than/less-than operators:

```js
console.log('b' > 'a') // true
console.log('b' < 'a') // false
```

Alphabetic characters occupy slots 65 (uppercase 'A') through 122 ( lowercase 'z') in the [ascii table](https://www.ascii-code.com/).

So for your purposes you could check whether each character is greater than or equal to 'A' and less than or equal to 'z'.

You could also use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to strip out non-letter characters.